# gcc - How to combine __attribute__((dllexport)) and [[nodiscard]] in a struct definition?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, c++17

I have a struct that is marked with the C++17's `[[nodiscard]]` attribute. It is defined like this:

```
struct [[nodiscard]] MyObject final
{
    explicit MyObject(int id);
    ~MyObject();

    MyObject(const MyObject&) = delete;
    MyObject& operator=(const MyObject&) = delete;

    int id;
};
```

Now I want to export it from my dynamic library.

On MSVC, the syntax `struct __declspec(dllexport) [[nodiscard]] MyObject final` works as expected.

But GCC fails to compile both `struct __attribute__((dllexport)) [[nodiscard]] MyObject final` and `struct [[nodiscard]] __attribute__((dllexport)) MyObject final`: the compiler just cannot handle such syntax.

And the syntax `__attribute__((dllexport)) struct [[nodiscard]] MyObject final` compiles but doesn't seem to do what I want, because it produces the following warning:

> :1:49: warning: attribute ignored in declaration of 'struct
>   MyObject' [-Wattributes]
>
> ```
> 1 | __attribute__((dllexport)) struct [[nodiscard]] MyObject final
>
>   |                                                 ^~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> :1:49: note: attribute for 'struct MyObject' must follow the
>   'struct' keyword

So, how can I export a `[[nodiscard]]` struct from a dynamic library on GCC?

Comment: Considering that Clang [handles](https://godbolt.org/z/nc6kgW) the `struct __attribute__((dllexport)) [[nodiscard]] MyObject` version, it might be a bug (or rather absence of a feature) in GCC.

Also note that GCC on Windows [handles](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: @andrey  The link you provided shows me the code with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` instead of `__attribute__((dllexport))`. And if I replace that with `__attribute__((dllexport))`, I get the following warning: `unknown attribute 'dllexport' ignored [-Wunknown-attributes]`.

Comment: That's because the Compiler Explorer node with Clang is running Linux. `dllexport` is for DLLs, which are Windows shared libraries. The equivalent attribute for shared libraries on Linux (and probably MacOS) is `visibility("default")` with `-fvisibility=hidden` on the command line. Naturally when building for Linux the compiler doesn't recognize the `dllexport` attribute (how ever it's written), but what matters, is that the attribute is parsed correctly (even if it's then ignored).

Comment: @andrey  Yes, I tested that code on Linux, but I didn't know much about creating shared libraries on Linux, so I thought that Linux compilers would be able to somehow recognize `dllexport` as well. Okay, so I should have used `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` instead. That's clear. Then, indeed, it's most likely a (yet another) GCC bug. If you write this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All of this applies to both `dllexport` and `dllimport`.*

This seems to be a bug in the GCC parser.

Clang [manages to parse](https://godbolt.org/z/dmkWo8) the `struct __attribute__((dllexport)) [[nodiscard]] MyObject ...` version.

As was noted by [@Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57994115/4567486), GCC (and Clang) support the C++ syntax for `dllexport` - `[[gnu::dllexport]]`.

Also it should be noted that GCC on Windows (MinGW) supports `__declspec(dllexport)` for compatibility with Visual C++ and actually parses `class __declspec(dllexport) [[nodiscard]] Test ...` correctly (tested with GCC 8.1.0).

---

All of the above assumes you're compiling for Windows, where `dllexport` actually means something. On other platforms the compiler will simply ignore it (and usually emit a warning).

On Linux one should use `-fvisibility=hidden` to hide all symbols except the ones chosen by the attribute `visibility("default")`. There is no "import" alternative - use `"default"` both when building and using the library. When exporting a class on Linux, anything that you don't want to export can then be marked with `visibility("hidden")` to override the class's attribute.

GCC and Clang support both syntaxes for `visibility`: `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` and `[[gnu::visibility("default")]]`.

More on visibility in GCC can be found [HERE](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

I'm not sure how exporting symbols from shared libraries works on MacOS (maybe the same as on Linux?).

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I also want to add that `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` and `[[gnu::visibility("default")]]` are not fully interchangeable. `__attribute((visibility("default"))) int foo();` and `int __attribute((visibility("default"))) foo();` are both valid, but the C++'s standard attributes syntax is more restrictive: `[[gnu::visibility("default")]] int foo();` works correctly while `int [[gnu::visibility("default")]] foo();` does not :(

Answer (score 4):

Try C++ attributes instead of using `__attribute__`:

```cpp
struct [[gnu::dllexport]] [[nodiscard]] MyObject final
```

And use a define to work with MSVC too

Comment: I don't think it'll work. I thought that `[[gnu::dllexport]]` might exist, and googled specifically for it before asking this question on stackoverflow. But I found nothing then. And now, when I try to compile your piece of code, I get the warning `'gnu::dllexport' scoped attribute directive ignored`, which means that `[[gnu::dllexport]]` is an unknown attribute to GCC.

Comment: @Taras I tried MinGW with GCC 8.1.0 and it recognized `[[gnu::dllexport]]` and `[[gnu::dllimport]]` (and the symbol was actually exported). Maybe you aren't on Windows?

Comment: @Taras Or maybe you are using an older version of GCC that doesn't support `[[gnu::dllexport]]`?

Comment: @andrey Replied to you in the comments above.

Comment: Another little question from me: isn't there any `[[gnu::...]]` alternative for `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`?

Comment: @Taras There is. It's [`[[gnu::visibility("default")]]`](https://godbolt.org/z/1_-bOP) :)

Comment: [At least clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#non-standard-c-11-attributes) accepts all `__attribute__((name))`s also as c++11 `[[gnu::name]]`. While I think GCC does the same, I found no mention.

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue as of 2022 in gcc. The gcc bugzilla entry for this is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69585